# When using a class, how can I restart a method but keep the current value of each variable inside?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I would like to keep the current value of restBill when I restart the function without restarting the restBill at 0, how would I go about doing that?

If I can't how would I go about letting them choose another item from the menu while staying inside the function?

```
class CasaMiaMember():

  menu = {
    "Wine" : 10,
    "Garlic Bread" : 5,
    "Calamari" : 10,
    "Pizza" : 8, 
    "Spaghetti" : 12,
    "Penne" : 13,
    "Rissotto" : 8,
    "Fish" : 15,
    "Pop" : 3,
    "Dessert" : 5
  }

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    if age >= 19:
      self.memFee = 225
    elif age <= 10:
      self.memFee = 0
    else:
      self.memFee = 225 * 0.50
    self.totalBill = self.memFee
    self.lottoNumber = random.randint(0, 1000000)

  def program(self):
    if self.age < 18:
      self.totalBill += 30
    else:
      self.totalBill += 100

  def restaurant(self):
    restBill = 0
    print ("Restaurant Bill is at: " + str(restBill))
    print ()
    for each in CasaMiaMember.menu:
      print (each + " : " + str(CasaMiaMember.menu[each]))
    choice = input("What Would You Like To Buy?: ")
    restBill += CasaMiaMember.menu[choice]
    nextItm = input("Would You Like To Buy Something Else? Y/N: ")  
    if nextItm == "Y":
      CasaMiaMember.restaurant(self)
    else:
      print ("That was Excellent!")
      print ("Subtotal: " + float(restBill))
      print ("HST: " + int(restBill * 0.13))
      restBillTotal = restBill * 0.13 + restBill
      print (restBillTotal)
      self.totalBill += restBillTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list instead, then add all the purchases to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop instead to continuously prompt for input until you get the exit case.

```
def restaurant(self):
    restBill = 0
    print("Restaurant Bill is at: " + str(restBill))
    print()
    for each in CasaMiaMember.menu:
        print (each + " : " + str(CasaMiaMember.menu[each]))

    while True: 
        choice = input("What Would You Like To Buy?: ")
        restBill += CasaMiaMember.menu[choice]
        nextItm = input("Would You Like To Buy Something Else? Y/N: ")  
        if nextItm == "N":
            break
    print("That was Excellent!")
    print("Subtotal: " + float(restBill))
    print("HST: " + int(restBill * 0.13))
    restBillTotal = restBill * 0.13 + restBill
    print(restBillTotal)
    self.totalBill += restBillTotal
```